# Line count as footer in xsl

Tags: xslt

I have an xml on which I am applying xsl to transform into pipe delimited file. I am able to get the output but I also need a record count at the end of file. Please help.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>    
 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="delimeter" select="'|'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lineFeed" select="'&#xa;'"/>
        
        <xsl:text>Headers</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$lineFeed"/>
        
        <!--<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">-->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:Worker_group/wd:Employee_ID"> 
            
            <!-- HDRCOM - Print Company Details -->
            <text>HDRCOM</text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:Company_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:Company_Address"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$lineFeed"/>            
              
            <!-- HDRBIO (Employee Information) -->
            <text>HDRBIO</text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:Full_Legal_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:Employee_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>                
            
            <!-- TAXES (Repeat the seqment for each type of Tax) -->
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="wd:Pay_Component_Category = 'Employee Paid Taxes'">
                        <text>TAXES</text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
                        
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Pay_Component"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
                        
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Amount"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>
                        
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:YTD_Amount"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$lineFeed"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>            
           
        <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
        </xsl:for-each-group>                       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output looks like:

HDRCOM|ABC|XYZ

HDRBIO|Andrew|12345

TAXES|Fed Withholdng A|         0.00|         0.00

TAXES|Fed Withholdng B|         1.95|         4.40

TAXES|Fed Withholdng C|         8.37|        18.83

HDRCOM|ABC|XYZ

HDRBIO|John|16543

TAXES|Fed Withholdng A|         1.00|         1.00

TAXES|Fed Withholdng B|         2.65|         4.40

TLR|          09  -----> I need this. TOTAL NUMBER OF LINES PRINTED.

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Company_Name>ABC</wd:Company_Name>
            <wd:Company_Address>XYZ</wd:Company_Address>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Andrew</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
            <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Pay_Component>Fed Withholdng A</wd:Pay_Component>
        <wd:Amount>0</wd:Amount>
        <wd:YTD_Amount>0</wd:YTD_Amount>
        <wd:Pay_Component_Category>Employee Paid Taxes</wd:Pay_Component_Category>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Company_Name>ABC</wd:Company_Name>
            <wd:Company_Address>XYZ</wd:Company_Address>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Andrew</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
            <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Pay_Component>Fed Withholdng B</wd:Pay_Component>
        <wd:Amount>1.95</wd:Amount>
        <wd:YTD_Amount>4.40</wd:YTD_Amount>
        <wd:Pay_Component_Category>Employee Paid Taxes</wd:Pay_Component_Category>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Company_Name>ABC</wd:Company_Name>
            <wd:Company_Address>XYZ</wd:Company_Address>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Andrew</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
            <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Pay_Component>Fed Withholdng C</wd:Pay_Component>
        <wd:Amount>8.37</wd:Amount>
        <wd:YTD_Amount>18.83</wd:YTD_Amount>
        <wd:Pay_Component_Category>Employee Paid Taxes</wd:Pay_Component_Category>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Company_Name>ABC</wd:Company_Name>
            <wd:Company_Address>XYZ</wd:Company_Address>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>John</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
            <wd:Employee_ID>16543</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Pay_Component>Fed Withholdng A</wd:Pay_Component>
        <wd:Amount>1</wd:Amount>
        <wd:YTD_Amount>1</wd:YTD_Amount>
        <wd:Pay_Component_Category>Employee Paid Taxes</wd:Pay_Component_Category>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Company_Name>ABC</wd:Company_Name>
            <wd:Company_Address>XYZ</wd:Company_Address>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>John</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
            <wd:Employee_ID>16543</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Pay_Component>Fed Withholdng B</wd:Pay_Component>
        <wd:Amount>2.65</wd:Amount>
        <wd:YTD_Amount>4.40</wd:YTD_Amount>
        <wd:Pay_Component_Category>Employee Paid Taxes</wd:Pay_Component_Category>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: Please show an example of the input. Reducing the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated my question to include input as suggested. Thanks

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to capture the textual record which you're generating as a string variable and then count the number of occurrences of line feed characters it contains.

```xml
<xsl:variable name="record">
<!-- insert your record-generation code here -->
</xsl:variable>
<!-- output the body of the record -->
<xsl:sequence select="$record"/>
<!-- compute the line count -->
<xsl:variable name="lines" select="count(tokenize($record, '\n')) + 1"/>
<!-- finally output the $lines information -->
```

You can use the `format-number()` function to format the line count with a leading zero if that's what you need. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-number

Comment: Well yes, you *could* do it this way. But it is so lame when you can simply calculate the number of items + 2 * the number of groups.

Comment: It's equal to the the number of items for which wd:Pay_Component_Category = 'Employee Paid Taxes', + 2 times the number of groups, isn't it?

Comment: What I would usually do in a situation like this is a two-step transformation: first transform the input data into XML (rather than lines of text, as done here). The XML would be like <row><cell>TAXES<cell><cell>Fed Withholdng A</cell><cell>0.00</cell><cell>0.00</cell></row>. I would capture that XML in a $record variable, and then transform it to the required textual form, and count the lines with count($record/row)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<xsl:output method="text"/>    
 
<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="Report_Entry[Pay_Component_Category = 'Employee Paid Taxes']" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-by="Worker_group/Employee_ID"> 
        <!-- HDRCOM - Print Company Details -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'HDRCOM', Worker_group/Company_Name, Worker_group/Company_Address" separator="|"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- HDRBIO (Employee Information) -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'HDRBIO', Worker_group/Full_Legal_Name, Worker_group/Employee_ID" separator="|"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- TAXES (Repeat the seqment for each type of Tax) -->        
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'TAXES', Pay_Component, Amount, YTD_Amount" separator="|"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>            
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
    <!-- count lines -->
    <xsl:value-of select="'TLR', count($items) + 2*count(distinct-values($items/Worker_group/Employee_ID))" separator="|"/>                    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there is a difference between my logic and yours: my method will not create headers for an empty group.